# Can parse a projection interface to object? Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

Actually have a projection interface in Spring. Like this:

```
public interface DaoObjectProjection{
    Integer getTotalAmount();
    String getCode();
    String getName();
    String getLastName();
}
```

And i want send this to another microservice, i know cant send the interface because the proxy funcionality dont work if use RestTemplate. For thar reason i use an another Object like that:

```
public class ObjectWantSend {
    private Integer totalAmount;
    private String code;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

//Getters
//Setters

}
```

My question if exist any way to parse directly my projection interface into this object or need setting one by one like this:

```
ObjectWantSend.setTotalAmount(DaoObjectProjection.getTotalAmount);
```

I am using Hibernate with Spring.

Comment: What do you mean by _proxy functionality_?

Comment: This [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces)  And this the quoted paragraph  `The query execution engine creates proxy instances of that interface at runtime for each element returned and forwards calls to the exposed methods to the target object.` @AndrewS

Comment: I don't see why using the interface in the REST call would not work.  However, in general, separate the local data access from additional downstream interactions.  Sometimes the local data structure does match what the downstream interaction is expecting, sometimes not.  See also: [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, if you want answer the question and give you the accepted. @AndrewS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, like other user says, you should use MapStruct. This could be a solution for your problem:

```
    @Mapper
    public interface ObjectMapper {

        ObjectMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( ObjectMapper.class );

        @Mapping(source = "totalAmount", target = "totalAmount")
        ObjectWantSend objectWantSend(DaoObjectProjection aux);
    }
```

That library works so good with Spring and Hibernate. I hope you find it usefull.